# jQuery Validate array input element which is created dynamically

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have a form which I want to validate using [the jQuery Validation plugin](http://jqueryvalidation.org/). I currently have an issue with input element with array (`name="inputname[]"`) which are created dynamically with jQuery `.on()`. Let me explain the issue:

1. There is a form, with one input text exist named `name[]`.
2. There is a button to add more input texts, and this element executed with .on(). I clicked 2 or 3 times so there will be more than 1 input texts.
3. I click submit, the form is correctly validate but it is only validate the first created array element and not the another element.

For full code I created a jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/ThE5K/4/

**jQuery**:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    // MODE 1
    //   With [] or array name <<<< this one is not working
    $("#addInput").on('click', function () {
        $('#inputs').append($('<input class="comment" name="name[]" />'));
    });


    /* MODE 2
       Without [] or array name <<<< this one is working
       var numberIncr = 1;

        $("#addInput").on('click', function () {
           $('#inputs').append($('<input class="comment" name="name' + numberIncr + '" />'));
           numberIncr++;
       });
    */

    $('form.commentForm').on('submit', function (event) {

        $('input.comment').each(function () {
            $(this).rules("add", {
                required: true
            })
        });

        event.preventDefault();

        console.log($('form.commentForm').valid());
    })

    $('form.commentForm').validate();
});
```

**HTML**:

```
<form class="commentForm">
    <div id="inputs"></div>
    <input type="submit" /> 
    <span id="addInput">add element</span>
</form>
```

I create two modes inside them, the working one (dynamic input text without array name) and the not working one (dynamic input text with array name).

I have been going though those solution but unfortunately no one of them worked:

- [jquery validate add rules for an array input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9996589/jquery-validate-add-rules-for-an-array-input)
- [jquery validate is not working with dynamic content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13170006/jquery-validate-is-not-working-with-dynamic-content)
- [jQuery validate dynamic input array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14943121/jquery-validate-dynamic-input-array)

Please help.

Comment: You are adding your rules when the form is submitted.  This is all wrong.  You should be adding your rules immediately after creating the new fields.

Comment: Please include enough code within OP to create a concise demo. Your OP should be fully "self-contained" and not be dependent upon external links.  I've edited your OP to include the full code.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Regarding your code for creating the new fields:

```
// Mode 1
$("#addInput").on('click', function () {
    $('#inputs').append($('<input class="comment" name="name[]" />'));
});
```

The entire reason your "Mode 1" was not working is because you've assigned the same exact name attribute, `name="name[]"`, to every single new `input`.  The jQuery Validate plugin *absolutely requires* that every `input` element have a *unique* `name` attribute.  Just use your `numberIncr` variable within `name[]` to ensure this unique name.

Also, you really should not be adding rules upon `submit`. The `submit` event is normally where all the rules are *checked*, so adding rules at this point does not make a lot of sense.  The new rules should be added when the new input fields are created.

For your simple case, the `rules('add')` method is overkill for this anyway and you can totally eliminate your `.on('submit')` handler.  Since the rule is `required`, you can simply add a `class="required"` to your new `input` elements.

Here is working code:

**jQuery**:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    // MODE 1
    var numberIncr = 1;
    $("#addInput").on('click', function () {
        $('#inputs').append($('<input class="comment required" name="name[' + numberIncr + ']" />'));
        numberIncr++;
    });

    $('form.commentForm').validate();
});
```

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/ThE5K/6/**

Comment: Hi Sparky, thank you for answer and warning.

I never know there is a name[1], name[2] (number inside [] brackets). However, first I need to know how PHP process this variable, so I will try your code ASAP...

Thanks.

Comment: Update: I am applying what do you suggest on my form, now everything works correctly (and perfectly) like a charm. I also able to eliminate .on(submit). Thanks!

Comment: @user9437856, please don't ask questions about your own question under answers elsewhere.  Nobody looking at this has any idea about your project or "controller".

Comment: @Sparky, asked this because you tag me this question.

Answer (score -1):

```
    The validation can be simply done by class name
        <form action="http://xxxx/project/create" class="form-horizontal" id="invoice_form" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="text" name="description[]" class="form-control validate_form" id="description"><span class="error">This field is required.</span></td>

                    <td><input type="text" name="per_litre[]" class="form-control validate_form validate_number per_litre"><span class="error">This field is required.</span><span class="error">Please enter number.</span></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="text" name="description[]" class="form-control validate_form" id="description"><span class="error">This field is required.</span></td>

                    <td><input type="text" name="per_litre[]" class="form-control validate_form validate_number per_litre"><span class="error">This field is required.</span><span class="error">Please enter number.</span></td>
                </tr>
            </table>

            <button type="submit" id="invoice_submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        </form>
```

---

```
Add style to hide error message:
     <style type="text/css">
        .error {
            color: red;
            display: none;
        }
    </style>
```

---

```
 Script for validate form fields by class name

    <script>
        $(document).on('click', '#invoice_submit', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            i = 0;
            $(".validate_form").each(function() {
                var selectedTr = $(this);
                var value = $(this).val();
                if (!value) {
                    selectedTr.next("span").show();
                    i++;
                } else {
                    selectedTr.next("span").hide();
                }
            });

            $(".validate_number").each(function() {
                var selectedTr = $(this);
                var value = $(this).val();

                var filter = /^[0-9]+([,.][0-9]+)?$/g;
                if (value != '') {
                    if (!filter.test(value)) {
                        selectedTr.next("span").next("span").show();
                        i++;
                    } else {
                      selectedTr.next("span").next("span").hide();
                    }
                }
            });
            if (i == 0) {
                $('#invoice_form').submit();
            }
        });
    </script>
```